# How to show a string on a page

Tags: javascript, html

This is a really stupid question.

I have a javascript string variable for a name, and i want to display it where it says *user* like this:

"Hello, *user*!" --> "Hello, Chris!

Comment: @esailija What do you mean? I just want to do something like "Hello, _variable_!"

Comment: `alert( "Hello, " + variable + "!" );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you could have found this answer out easily yourself :p

Put the name in a span and give it an ID

```
Hello <span id="name"></span>
```

Then set the text using getElementByID

```
var name = "Chris";
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
```

Comment: This approach is still vunerable to injection attacks.  You may want to create a text node.  Something like this:

    document.getElementById("name").appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));

If you're using a framework like jQuery, this is a bit more concise:

    $("#name").text(name);

Answer (score 1):

```
var user_name = 'Chris';
document.writeln("Hello, " + user_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the user's name with the rest of the string you want to display like so:

```
<p id="hello"></p>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var user_name = "Chris";
var hello_string = "Hello, " + user_name;
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = hello_string;
</script>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to actually print the string to an element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think [document.write](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp) plus some string concatenation are what you're looking for:

```
var user = "Chris";
document.write("Hello, " + user + "!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick.

```
var user = 'Steve';

document.write('hello ' + user);
```

If you need to target an element, you can use the usual methods, such as:

```
var user = 'Steve';

var thisOne = document.getElementById('thisOne');

thisOne.innerHTML = ('hello ' + user);
```

May as well throw in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/4gknV/) so you can play around an experiment.

Comment: _Exactly_ what i wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is example of dislay string into span tag.
'+' operator uses for string concatenation.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var name = 'Chris';
    var field = document.getElementById('show_string');
    field.innerHTML( '"Hello, '+ name + '!"' );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id='show_string'></span>
</body>
</html>
```